# Adding new object with different values to a hashmap by using the same object creation

Tags: java

```
Ticket ticketObject = new Ticket(); //I create my object here
HashMap<Integer, Ticket> totalTickets = new HashMap<Integer, Ticket>(); //I create the hasmap
totalTickets.put(counter, ticketObject); // And after i have given values to my object via setters and getters I add i to has map
```

above let's say is my main class then, I re-run the main function by using:

```
main(args);
```

And when it tries to add a ticketObject to the hasmap with different values it doesn't. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: What is counter in your example ? How do you get it ?

Comment: A random number by random library, it's the key nothing really important, sorry for not mentioning

Comment: We need to see your code

Comment: can you please provide a runnable example? That makes it a lot easier to understand what you want to do exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each value object of the hash map will be mapped to an integer object. So, you can't aasign two different values to the same object.

You have to take care with boxed Integer because you will get the same object if you make "new Integer(1)" twice, for example, because the class has internal cache of integers. Check the method of Integer.valueof to understand better this behavior.

Check this article:
https://javapapers.com/java/java-integer-cache/

Comment: I changed the counter since it was overriding my previous object. That was the mistake, thank you and sorry for the missunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Ticket {

private String type; // "normal" "reduced"
private String kind; // "online" "printed"
private int duration;
private int trips;
private int serial;

public void constuct( ) {
    type = "";
    kind = "";
    duration = 0;
    trips = 0;
    serial = 0;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public String getKind() {
    return kind;
}

public int getDuration() {
    return duration;
}

public int getTrips() {
    return trips;
}

public void setType(String newType) {
    type = newType;
}

public void setKind(String newKind) {
    kind = newKind;
}

public void setDuration(int newDuration) {
    duration = newDuration;
}

public void setTrips(int newTrips) {
    trips = newTrips;
}

public int getSerial() {
    return serial;
}

public void setSerial(int serial) {
    this.serial = serial;
}
```

}

here is my Ticket class

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int menuChoice;
    int counter = 0;
    Ticket ticketObject = new Ticket();
    SubTicket subTicketObject = new SubTicket();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Menu menuObject = new Menu();
    HashMap<Integer, Ticket> totalTickets = new HashMap<Integer, Ticket>();
    ticketObject.constuct();
    subTicketObject.constuctt();
    menuObject.printMainMenu();
    menuObject.printChoice();
    menuChoice = input.nextInt();

    switch (menuChoice) {
    case 1:
        menuObject.printChoiceType();
        input.nextLine(); // throw away the /n
        String tmp = input.nextLine();
        if(tmp.equals("normal")) {
            ticketObject.setType("normal");
            menuObject.printChoiceTripsDur();
            String tmp2 = input.nextLine();
            if(tmp2.equals("trips")) {
                menuObject.printTripsAmount();
                int tripsAmount = input.nextInt();
                if(tripsAmount!=1 || tripsAmount != 5 || tripsAmount!=11) {
                    menuObject.printError();
                    break;
                }
                ticketObject.setTrips(tripsAmount);
                System.out.println(ticketObject.getTrips());
            }else if(tmp2.equals("duration")){
                menuObject.printDurationAmount();
                int durationAmount = input.nextInt();
                switch (durationAmount){
                case 1:
                    counter++;
                    ticketObject.setDuration(90);
                    System.out.println("Your ticket serial is " + counter);
                    menuObject.printType();
                    int tmptype = input.nextInt();
                    if(tmptype == 1) {
                        subTicketObject.setType("online");
                    }else if(tmptype == 2){
                        subTicketObject.setType("printed");
                    }else {
                        menuObject.printError();
                    }

                    totalTickets.put(counter, ticketObject);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    counter++;
                    ticketObject.setDuration(1440);
                    System.out.println("Your ticket serial is " + counter);
                    menuObject.printType();
                    int tmptype3 = input.nextInt();
                    if(tmptype3 == 1) {
                        subTicketObject.setType("online");
                    }else if(tmptype3 == 2){
                        subTicketObject.setType("printed");
                    }else {
                        menuObject.printError();
                    }

                    totalTickets.put(counter, ticketObject);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    counter++;
                    ticketObject.setDuration(1080);
                    System.out.println("Your ticket serial is " + counter);
                    menuObject.printType();
                    int tmptype2 = input.nextInt();
                    if(tmptype2 == 1) {
                        subTicketObject.setType("online");
                    }else if(tmptype2 == 2){
                        subTicketObject.setType("printed");
                    }else {
                        menuObject.printError();
                    }

                    totalTickets.put(counter, ticketObject);    
                    break;
                case 4:
                    counter++;
                    subTicketObject.setDuration(43200);
                    menuObject.printAskUserFirstName();
                    input.nextLine(); // throw away the /n
                    String tmpfirstname = input.nextLine();
                    subTicketObject.setFirstname(tmpfirstname);
                    menuObject.printAskUserSecondName();
                    String tmpsecondname = input.nextLine();
                    subTicketObject.setFirstname(tmpsecondname);
                    menuObject.print30DurationPrice();
                    menuObject.printHowToPay();
                    int tmppay = input.nextInt();
                    if(tmppay == 1) {
                        menuObject.printInsertCash();
                    }else if(tmppay == 2) {
                        menuObject.printInsertCard();
                    }else {
                        menuObject.printError();
                    }
                    System.out.println("Your ticket serial is " + counter);
                    menuObject.printType();
                    int tmptype5 = input.nextInt();
                    if(tmptype5 == 1) {
                        subTicketObject.setType("online");
                    }else if(tmptype5 == 2){
                        subTicketObject.setType("printed");
                    }else {
                        menuObject.printError();
                    }
                    totalTickets.put(counter, subTicketObject); 
                    break;
                default:
                    menuObject.printError();
                    break;
                }

            }

        }else if(tmp.equals("reduced")) {
            ticketObject.setType("reduced");
            // gotta ask for "stoixeia" here and save them somewhere


        }else {
            menuObject.printError();
        }

    }
    System.out.println(totalTickets);
    menuObject.printKeepRunning();
    int tmprun = input.nextInt();
    if (tmprun == 1) {
        main(args);
    }

}
```

}

here is my main

```
public class SubTicket extends Ticket{

private String firstname;
private String secondname;

public void constuctt( ) {
    firstname = "";
    secondname = "";

}

public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}
public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}
public String getSecondname() {
    return secondname;
}
public void setSecondname(String secondname) {
    this.secondname = secondname;
}
```

}
and here is my SubTicket, the subclass

Comment: The problem is that the user gives the input for the ticketObject, so I can't just create tickets randomly, I want the user to give the input and then add that input as an object to my hashmap

Comment: Ok. Just a comment. There are switch cases with many lines under each which is not desirable and make it harder to for someone read the code!

Answer (score 0):

First of all the question is not clear. Please confirm if you are trying to add different counters as Key or for the same key you are trying to add ticketObject with different values.
If you are trying to map the different value to the same key, it will override the previous ticketObject as shown below.

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class TestMap {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] counterArgs= {"1","2","3"};

        Ticket ticketObject = (new TestMap()).new Ticket();
            // I create my object here
        HashMap<Integer, Ticket> totalTickets = new HashMap<Integer, Ticket>(); 
        for (String counter : counterArgs) {
            ticketObject.setCounter(Integer.valueOf(counter));
            totalTickets.put(Integer.valueOf(counter), ticketObject); 
        }

        totalTickets.entrySet().forEach(e->System.out.println(e.getKey()+"-"+e.getValue()));


    }

    class Ticket {
        public int getCounter() {
            return counter;
        }

        public void setCounter(int num) {
            this.counter = num;
        }

        int counter;
        @Override
        public String toString(){

            return ""+counter;

        }
    }

}
```

output:

```
1-3
2-3
3-3
```